# Enable <textarea> to display HTML content,such as bold,italic,color,img tags

Tags: php, mysql, html, textarea

I'll try to be clear in the question,i need to display HTML content on a .Let me explain what i trying to do.

1-On my main file i have a  which sends the text inserted to a mysql table.(OK)
2-After on the same page PHP execute a query and search for the rows containing an id inserted together with the message.(OK)
3-After the PHP found the rows with the same id i display these messages using the code bellow(the messages are displayed on a textarea):

```
while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_two)){

   $horario = $runrows['added'];
   $autor = $runrows['autor'];
   $mensagem = $runrows['mensagem'];
   $codigosender = $runrows['codigosender'];

   $testevar = htmlspecialchars($mensagem);

   echo"
   <center>
   <table width='500px;'>
   <tr><td width='75%'>$autor</td><td width='25%'>$horario</td></tr>
   </table>
   <textarea name='displayMessages' style=' width:500px;' readonly>$testevar</textarea>
   </center>

   ";

   }
```

Now is my problem: If i insert on my sender  the message '**(bold tag)Mateus(bold tag)**',when the PHP display on the textarea it doesn't display the 'Mateus' in bold!So how can i enable the textarea to do so?(Basically i want to enable my textarea to work as this one i writing now).

Comment: `php` tag is absolutely irrelevant to the question. Anyway, just get tinymce or CKEditor

Comment: This textarea (on stackoverflow) does not have bold or italic or anything.

Comment: when you are writing any question you are allowed to use tags such as <b>,<i>,or insert images

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you display styles in a HTML textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245507/how-do-you-display-styles-in-a-html-textarea)

Comment: `the code is inside php tags` -- and the code is written in windows operating system. Let's put windows here as well. And please - `coffee`, because I'm currently drinking coffee

Comment: Textarea displays raw HTML/plain text #coffee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML textarea will not have any styling for the value it contents.

if you wish to give styling you will need to use third party controls. like CKEditor, or freetext Box, otherwise you will need to create your own textarea.

Comment: When i just put echo"$mensagem"; all html entities are displayed well,but when i add my string to a textarea it just display as text.I want to know if it is possible to make a textarea display the htmlentities.

Comment: No there is no such way to display the data or value in textarea using html tags, for that we will have to use thrid party controls only, but inside textarea u cannot so the style, yes tags are visible..

Answer (score 1):

As other have explained, you cannot style the contents of a TextArea element.

However, you *can* take the other route and make a standard `div` editable if you set its contentEditable property to `true`. This makes the `div` element behave similarly to a text area. Of course, to actually let the user change styles, you would have to add some external controls (buttons, bind keypress events, etc.) See a nice example at [Joe Armstrong's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20150712053536/http://whoomph.net/contentEditable/mini1.html)

But the easiest method is probably to just use CKEditor or similar package.

Answer (score 0):

As other have explained. i have some solution like below code. actually I created a **div** then I converted it as **textarea** then my php code.

its working for me properly please try it at once. I think you got your answer.

```
 <div style="height: 100px;overflow-y: scroll;text-rendering:     auto;overflow: auto;resize: vertical;">

 <?php echo nl2br($value['rt_master_conversation']); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: <div style="height: 100px;overflow-y: scroll;text-rendering: auto;overflow: auto;resize: vertical;">
     <?php echo nl2br($value['rt_master_conversation']); ?> </div>

Comment: this code is working for me

Comment: Please edit your answer to add more details.